# How to connect a different (external) wordpress database server to another wordpress server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. This is what I want to setup.

There are 2 wordpress servers. One is the database server and the other is application. Only the database server will be used to update the site. The other wp-site will look at the DB site and show it's content. How is this configuration possible?

I have tried the following config but it is not working. Pls help!

```
define(‘DB_NAME’, ‘myserver’);

/** MySQL database username */

define(‘DB_USER’, ‘user’);

/** MySQL database password */

define(‘DB_PASSWORD’, ‘password’);

/** MySQL hostname */
define(‘DB_HOST’, ‘IP’);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to host wordpress database from other server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569889/is-it-possible-to-host-wordpress-database-from-other-server)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

In your **config.php** file on your application server:

```
define(‘DB_NAME’, ‘your-database-name’);
define(‘DB_USER’, ‘your-database-user-name’);
define(‘DB_PASSWORD’, ‘your-database-user-password’);
define(‘DB_HOST’, ‘the-ip-address-of-your-database-server’);
```