# INSERT data INTO custom database - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have an e-commerce website running on woocommerce and I want to store order information in non-wordpress database. When a user clicks on `Place Order` then the order details should get stored in a custom database.

Can anyone please suggest me with how can I achieve this? BTW I am a newbie to WordPress.

Comment: Can you specify what you do mean by custom database? Are you referring to the MySQL database that you created while installing WordPress for your eCommerce website?

Comment: Mysql database on another server.

Comment: Please check the answer on similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569889/is-it-possible-to-host-wordpress-database-from-other-server